# structure and linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

```
struct node
{
int info;
struct node *link;
}*start;
void main()
{
struct node*tmp,*q;
tmp=(struct node*)malloc sizeof(struct node);
}
```

now my first question is when we declare structure is any struct type node is created in memory?

second question is ,if yes then here i take a start pointer which is pointing to struct type node so without specifying the address of struct node to start pointer how start pointer pointing the struct type node which is created during declaration plz clear me this how internally this is happening i have lot of confusion on that

third question is initially tmp and q pointer variable all are pointing towards the same struct node

plz expalin the concept malloc and calloc how internally they create node 
thx for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can declare a structure type without declaring any variables.  However, your code defines a pointer variable, `start`.
2. The variable `start` is initialized to 0, so it is not pointing to anything.
3. The variables `tmp` and `q` are not initialized at all and cannot be safely used until assigned a value.  You initialize `tmp` in the next line; `q` is still uninitialized.
4. `malloc()` provides space for the pointer to point to; it does not initialize that space.  The value in `tmp->info` is indeterminate; the value in `tmp->link` is indeterminate too.  If you had used `calloc()`, then `tmp->info` would be zero and `tmp->link` would be null (on all practical systems — theoretically, there could be a system where `tmp->link` was not properly initialized).

Finally, note that `void main()` is bad.  The C standard says that the return type of `main()` should be `int`.  Further, unless you've got a C99 or later compiler, you should include `return(0);` or equivalent as the last line in `main()` — or a call to `exit()`.

Comment: To 3.) tmp is initialized in the last line .. however the whole rest is not.

Comment: @Jonathen Leffler sir  if start is not pointing to any node so if provide the information to structure through start->info=45 then this value is easily accessible through another pointer printf("%d",p->info); if p pointer is declared beside start pointer like      struct node{ int info,struct node *link}*start,*p;

Comment: @Alex: we can split hairs and say '`tmp` is not initialized; it is assigned to on the line with `malloc()`', and that's correct.  You're correct that when the assignment occurs, the pointer has a sensible value, though the information it points at is not initialized.

Comment: @ankurjadiya: If `start` is not pointing to any node, any use of `start->info` is going to lead to problems, most likely a crash.  In C, you have to make sure that a pointer is pointing somewhere valid before you try using it.  After a while, it becomes second nature, but when starting out, it takes some getting used to.  If you do something like: `struct node root = { 0, 0 };` and then write `start = &root;`, then you can execute `start->info = 45;` and `struct node *p = start;` and `printf("%d\n", p->info);`.  But note how I had to make sure `p` pointed to the same place as `start`.